# Not able to get device token using GCM in test and QA environment

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to test my application in test environment. GCM not able to register the device and returning blank token ID. But it is working properly in Production environment (getting token ID). I am using the same code and pointing to different environments.

What might be the cause? Is there anything that we need to do with server side?

Please help in solving this issue, i have been working on it from past two days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might have not added sha1 using debug key store in google dev console. plus you must migrate to fcm as per google recommnedation

Comment: Hi Praveen. First off, Google has already announced [GCM's deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641313/4625829), so you should proceed with using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) now. With that said, it would be easier for the community to help you out if you actually include the codes that you currently have which you think isn't working --  however, I would still strongly suggest you try out FCM first and come back here if it doesn't work.

Comment: Found that my company's VPN is blocking the tokens. In production there will be no VPN and working fine.