# Android: GCM Push Notification error "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH" at App server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Problem:**

1)Android App with senderId And serverkey working good till last week, able to receive the push notifications.

2)senderId And serverkey were generated on last year(Creation date
Aug 31, 2017, 5:10:20 PM).

3)Now app server gets error "2018-09-05 12:52:04.289 pid:29578 worker:2 error: Push Notification error : "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"

**Questions:**

1)free GCM service used and is there whitelisting after a year?

2)https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode

SENDER_ID_MISMATCH  The authenticated sender ID is different from the sender ID for the registration token.

This is not in my case. Hows the GCM server reporting SENDER_ID_MISMATCH? Is it a google bug?

3)App is still with GCM and not moved to FCM and uses InstanceID
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID

will it be issue?

4)Application is able to get token for google and server and send to app server.

Below device side error is linked to this?

09-06 19:19:11.456 3088-7737/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: , App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller
fzk: Long live credential not available.

Answer (score 1):

1. There isn't.
2. Not a question.
3. The [GCM service has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641313/4625829), but will be completely removed by April 2019. I don't think that this is causing the issue, it might be possible. Every service that has been deprecated should migrate asap to avoid unexpected behaviors (such as this one?).
4. AFAIK, that's not a log that is related to GCM. It's probably related to actual authentication.

In general, posts with multiple questions isn't a good practice -- usually voted as too broad. I would strongly suggest that you split your questions in different post while providing as much details as you can.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.. #2 is question if the Google server has a bug sending wrong msg?

Comment: If it is, then it would most probably be a bug. I suggest contacting Google Support directly so that they could check the details on their end. From your post, it's hard to tell if it's the actual code that's the issue -- but since you didn't do much changes and it just started to happen, then it is possible that it might be a bug. Cheers!