# GCM - Android Push Notification - MismatchSenderId Error

Tags: c#, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I get an error that cannot fixed during using GCM service. I added push notification actions to my app recently.

When I try to send a push notification, then I'm always getting this error in JSON response:

**"MismatchSenderId"**

*Detail:*

```
{
  "ClassName": "PushSharp.Android.GcmMessageTransportException",
  "Message": "MismatchSenderId",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": null,
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

I searched all similar issues on StackOverflow and other platforms etc. , tried all suggested solutions, but didn't work.

- I create an API key after created my project through https://console.cloud.google.com (Also tried to removing available API keys and using the created new one)
- I get Project Number to using for SenderId parameter (through https://console.cloud.google.com)
- I set GCM_PackageName as my android app package name like defined in Google Store.

Also,

- I tried to use API Key generated through https://console.firebase.google.com/project/

PS: Project Numbers values are same in console.cloud and console.firebase

All didn't work for me.

When I try to use API key created through console.cloud, I get "Authenticated Error".

When I try to use API key created through console.firebase, I get mentioned error.. "MismatchSenderId". (I'm trying to make progress on this way)

Also there is an other point:

- When I use my friends app's GCM config parameters (SenderId, API key etc.) on my project, I can send push notification to somebody using specified gcm address through his app.
  (My friend has gotten those config paramaters via old Google Console pages, also his app is available on Google Store)

So there is not seen a problem with my server or GCM PushSharp service codes. My friend hasn't changed his working config parameter for years. Maybe Google changed its GCM configurations on developer console during GCM -> Firebase system and I can't find true parameters on console for config...

I cannot figure out this issue for days, please help me.

Regards

Comment: [GCM is deprecated and will be removed next month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641313/4625829). Any reason why you're not starting with FCM? MismatchSenderId occurs when you're sending to a registration token that isn't associated with your project. You mentioned you searched similar issues in SO, do point them out to help narrow down what you've actually checked. Currently, this post can be tagged as a duplicate of the other MismatchSenderId posts because no code is also shown.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I missed that point (GCM already depraceted) Actually, I was aware that GCM will be deprecated on April 2019, but I wanted to use present code. Many thanks.