# Got exception "Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to create Unity plugin for one of push notification service. I've add this to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="${applicationId}" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- PROTECTION_NORMAL -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Protection unknown -->
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

       <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
</manifest>
```

But when i send push notification to my client app will get this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.chabok.io.starter.unity-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.chabok.io.starter.unity-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.chabok.io.starter.unity-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2787)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1484)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.chabok.io.starter.unity-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.chabok.io.starter.unity-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.chabok.io.starter.unity-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
```

I really need to fix this and i don't know how

Comment: [GCM will be removed next month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39640981/4625829). If you're just starting to create the app, then start with FCM.

Comment: @AL. Thanks, But server-side use FCM and it's not my library