# Is there any work around to use Fcm device id with Gcm backend?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

The problem is we have GCM integrated at the backend and when I try to add a new app to console it takes me to Firebase console when I click on google could messaging and when I send firebase device id to backend it is using GCM library to send notifications and gives mismatch sender id error. I know we have to implement FCM at the backend but is there any work around for sending notifications using GCM while using FCM device id from the backend?

Comment: You need to update your server endpoints for FCM ID. Read migration guides for GCM to FCM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_server_endpoints

Comment: i know we have to migrate to FCM backend but the thing is we are in very tight deadline we just came to know about this problem so i want to know is any temprory fix or work around is available?

Comment: Tell you Backend developer to replace your current GCM URL to  this URL :https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send (please add https://)

Comment: That migration is easy. Its just url changes and stuff. your backend dev should be able to do it. There is no more shortcut than that

Comment: ok thank you @kapsym and Himesh Goswami

Comment: [FCM is backwards compatible with GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39565070/4625829). MismatchSenderId is pointing a different error.